# Number of days between today and a certain date (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, date

I have a dataframe df which looks like this. Date is in a text format.

| Reference | date |
| --- | --- |
| RefA | 2022-11-24 |
| RefB | 2021-05-14 |
| ... | ... |

My question is seemingly simple - I would like to create a new column, with for each Reference the time difference (in days) between the date and today.
I searched and tried several things, which are not working and I am struggling to understand why.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['days_diff_from_today'] = (pd.to_datetime('today')-df.date).dt.days
```

This returns TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

So I tried converting my str in a date but...

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['days_diff_from_today'] = (pd.to_datetime('today')-df.date).dt.days
```

This returns "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct syntax here ?
Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your date column currently has data type string instead of datetime64.

```
df['days_diff_from_today'] = np.datetime64('today') - df['date'].astype('datetime64')
```

Alternatively, if you want your date column to be in datetime.

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype('datetime64')
df['days_diff_from_today'] = np.datetime64('today') - df['date']
```